# How to implement GlobalMinPool2D function in keras layers?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, keras-layer, max-pooling

keras layers provide `keras.layers.GlobalAvgPool2D` and `keras.layers.GlobalAvgPool2D` api to implement global average  2d pooling and max pooling. But, Min Pooling also may be useful,and now I want to use  GlobalMinPool2D, which the keras layers api haven't implement.So How to write the code to implement the keras layers GlobalMinPool2D?

Comment: Note that `min_pool(inputs) == -1 * max_pool(-1 * inputs)`. That is, negating the inputs and taking the maximum is taking the minimum of the original inputs, and negating again restores the original.

Answer (score 0):

We can create a custom layer and call `tf.keras.backend.min()` with `axis=[1,2]` to perform the global min pooling operation. This is similar to `GlobalMaxPool2D` as seen in its [source](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/blob/v2.6.0/keras/layers/pooling.py#L1135-L1184).

```
 class GlobalMinPool2D( tf.keras.layers.Layer ):

    def call(self , inputs ):
        return tf.keras.backend.min( inputs , axis=[ 1 , 2 ] )
```

We can try it with a tensor like,

```
layer = GlobalMinPool2D()
x = np.random.randn( 32 , 128 , 128 , 3 )
print( layer(x).shape )
```

The output,

```
(32, 3)
```